# HTML Range Slider Buttons offset differently in different browsers

Tags: html

I have a bank of ten buttons, then a bank of range sliders rotated through 90degrees so they are vertical placed on top of the buttons for reasons too long to explain here.

This works fine but the sliders are offset relative to the buttons underneath by different amounts depending on the browser.  By varying the width and margin-left parameters in the CSS .slider block I can centralise the slider for any browser, but only with different numbers for each browser.  The code shown has them central on Chrome on Android, offset to the left on Firefox on Windows, and offset to the right on Chromium on Raspian !

(The slider background uses px rather than vw as these are usually an image, but I've changed it to a solid colour to make the code run here).

I don't really want to use browser specific code so can somebody see why this happens and suggest a fix ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Slider Problem Demo</title>

    <style>
        body, html 
        {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .main
        {
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .slider_wrapper 
        {
            position: relative;
        }

        .slider_navi 
        {
            height: 25vw;
        }

        #slider_place 
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 4vw;
        }

        .slibut
        {
            width : 3vw;
            height : 100%;
            margin-left : 3vw;
            margin-right : 3vw;
            background-color: #C00000;
        }

        .slider 
        {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 2.2vw;
            margin-left : 6.8vw;
        }

        .slider input 
        {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            width: 17vw;
            height: 1vw;
            background: #000000;
            transform-origin: 8.5vw 8.5vw;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }

        .slider input::-webkit-slider-thumb 
        {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 0vw;
            background: #0000C0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .slider input::-moz-range-thumb 
        {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 0vw;
            background: #0000C0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>



<body>
    <div class = 'main'>
        <div class='slider_wrapper'>
            <div class='slider_navi'>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut1'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut2'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut3'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut4'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut5'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut6'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut7'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut8'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut9'> </button>
                <button class = 'slibut' id = 'slibut10'> </button>
            </div>

            <div id='slider_place'>
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide1'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div>
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide2'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div>
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide3'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div> 
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide4'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div> 
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide5'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div> 
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide6'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div> 
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide7'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div> 
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide8'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div> 
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide9'  type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div> 
                <div class='slider'> <input id = 'slide10' type = 'range' min = '0' max = '127' oninput = 'Update(0)'> </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function update(num)
        {
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe use a proper normalisation css framework

Comment: I looked in normalise.css before asking to see if it helped but it doesn't seem to deal with range sliders.